# Show that $\sin z$ has only one series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, roots

The question goes: An extension of the real function $\sin x$ into a complex analytic function is by defining $\sin z = z- z^3/3! + z^5/5!- \cdots$. Show that this is the only way6 to extend $\sin x$ to a complex analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$.

We are working on zeroes and singularities so it is probably related to this topic.

My trial: I know that $\sin z$ has order of zero $1$ from the given expansion $\sin z = z- z^3/3! + z^5/5!- \cdots$. I can also let $\sin z$ have another series expansion. But since the zeroes of $\sin z$ are $k\pi i$ which are all of multiplicity $1$, these two are the same function. I don't know if I am doing this correctly, and I don't know a sound way of getting the multiplicity of the zeroes of $\sin z$ either.

Can someone help me with this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Suppose that there is another analytic extension $g(z)$ of $\sin(x)$. Since $h(z)=g(z)-(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+...)=0$ on the real line, we have a dense set of values where $h(z)=0$. Therefore $h$ is identically zero. I think you can finish from here.